# Angular Material progress bar, using custom colors

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have a Angular 5 project where I’m using a material progress bar. I want to use custom colors. I’ve tried several workarounds (including previous SO questions) , but cannot break the code. I want to change the color based on percent progress. HTML:

```
<mat-progress-bar *ngIf="cell.name === 'progress'" [value]="cell.value" 
    class="mat-progress-bar-round my-color" [ngClass]="'color ' + ((cell.value <= 
     30) ? 'color-red' : (cell.value < 70) ? 'color-yellow' : 'color-green')">   
    </mat-progress-bar>`
```

sass (css):

```
   mat-progress-bar {
      &.mat-progress-bar-big {
        padding: 13px 0;
      }

      &.mat-progress-bar-round {
        border-radius: 11px;
        height: 6px;

        .mat-progress-bar-buffer {
          background-color: $grey3;
        }

        .mat-progress-bar-fill {
          &::after {
            border-radius: 11px;
          }
        }

        &.color {
          .mat-progress-bar-fill {
            &::after {
              animation: none;
              content: '';
              display: inline-block;
              left: 0;
            }
          }

          &.color-red {
            .mat-progress-bar-fill {
              &::after {
            background-color: $red;
              }
            }
          }

          &.color-yellow {
            .mat-progress-bar-fill {
              &::after {
                background-color: $yellow;
              }
            }
          }

          &.color-green {
            .mat-progress-bar-fill {
              &::after {
                background-color: $green;
              }
            }
          }

          &.color-aqua {
            .mat-progress-bar-fill {
              &::after {
                background-color: $aqua;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Any help VERY much appreciated...:-)

Comment: What isn't working? The color styles or the ngClass?

Comment: [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56917234/1160236). It uses a custom directive to change mat-progress-bar color dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P98jU.png

```
/deep/ .mat-progress-bar-fill::after {
    background-color: green;
}

/deep/ .mat-progress-bar-buffer {
    background: #E4E8EB;
}
```

Comment: Angular is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the color in .ts file worked for me

```html
<mat-progress-bar [value]="cell.value"  [color]="cell.color">   
</mat-progress-bar>
```

and in .ts file,

```ts
cell.color = 'primary'; //predefined color in default theme
```

I believe you can replace 'primary' with your custom color

Comment: Using [color] and setting theme colors works fine. What U mention works OK for me too.Try using a custom color, not a theme color.

Comment: The color property only accepts three values: `primary`/`accent`/`warn`