# Change angular material progress bar color from code

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to change the color of [angular material progress bar](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/overview) dynamically.
I realized that it is not that simple, so what is the best way to to it?

requirements:

1. I will receive the color hex code from an external API. So I can not create a set of predefined themes
2. The background color will be white. So, I just need one color, not the entire palette (lighter, darker) colors.

related link: [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50931171/angular-material-progress-bar-using-custom-colors)

Comment: Probably the duplicate of [Angular - Material: Progressbar custom color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48869915/angular-material-progressbar-custom-color)

Comment: I honestly don't think this possible to do without a hack of some sort. Theming will be improved in the future as stated in the official doc.

Comment: Watch the answer of Simonca in the linked question. Join that solution with `ngClass`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular - Material: Progressbar custom color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48869915/angular-material-progressbar-custom-color)

Comment: Not duplicate. How to receive the color and apply it dynamically?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm getting all colors, logos, content, etc. out of a CMS and have to programmatically change the page accordingly. Has anyone found a clean solution to this? The selected answer doesn't seem to fulfill the requirements.

Comment: @BenRoberts WHat about Ryan Meyers' answer?

Comment: @guilhermecgs  did you get the solution change it dynamically ?

Comment: @JoelJoseph, I just need to change between 4 predefined colors. So I hardcoded each color on the css. I used @meetdave´s solution

Comment: this should be on the component api! plz angular team!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We can create an attribute directive which accepts the color value and override default styles of `<mat-progress-bar>` for us.

here is a working demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-progress-bar-color-directive

here is a brief explanation:

If we inspect `<mat-progress-bar>` in developer tools. we will find that color of the progress-bar is defined in the `::after` pseudo element like this.

```
.mat-progress-bar-fill::after {
    background-color: #3f51b5;
}
```

And as we already know that it is not possible to *directly manipulate* a pseudo element using DOM querySelector() method. But we can add new styles which can have rules for pseudo elements too. checkout this thread for more details. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21709814/1160236

So, we can make a directive which can take care of adding new styles for us.

```
import { Directive, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appProgressBarColor]'
})
export class ProgressBarColor implements OnChanges{
  static counter = 0;

  @Input() appProgressBarColor;
  styleEl:HTMLStyleElement = document.createElement('style');

  //generate unique attribule which we will use to minimise the scope of our dynamic style 
  uniqueAttr = `app-progress-bar-color-${ProgressBarColor.counter++}`;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { 
    const nativeEl: HTMLElement = this.el.nativeElement;
    nativeEl.setAttribute(this.uniqueAttr,'');
    nativeEl.appendChild(this.styleEl);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void{
    this.updateColor();
  }

  updateColor(): void{
    // update dynamic style with the uniqueAttr
    this.styleEl.innerText = `
      [${this.uniqueAttr}] .mat-progress-bar-fill::after {
        background-color: ${this.appProgressBarColor};
      }
    `;
  }

}
```

as you can see that all that we are doing here is just making a new `HtmlStyleElement` and adding it just inside the host element.

And inside `updateColor()` method we are updating the `innerText` of the style tag we have appended. notice that we are using an attribute selector here with a unique attribute to minimize the scope of the style to the host only. because we want to override the style only for that progress-bar on which we have applied our directive.

you can use this directive in your template like this.

```
<mat-progress-bar [appProgressBarColor]="'orange'"
                  mode="determinate" 
                  value="40"></mat-progress-bar>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work in Angular 11 until I added a class name to the native element and the style. For example, "nativeEl.classList.add('progress-bar-custom-color');" and ".progress-bar-custom-color[${this.uniqueAttr}] .mat-progress-bar-fill::after"...

Comment: WOW !!!!... Awesome solution !!!

Answer (score 13):

Update:

Avoid using deep, 
**TL;DR**: Deep is technically invalid (like, deeprecated :p)

For more info refer: [The use of /deep/ and >>> in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42134355/the-use-of-deep-and-in-angular-2)

Now, to change the color of mat-progress bar,

Head over to your styles.scss file (or the main css/scss file in your project)

Add this class -->

```
.green-progress .mat-progress-bar-fill::after {
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

Your mat-progress should use the above class, like -->

```
<mat-progress-bar class="green-progress" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
```

Comment: Best response to achieve it: shorter and simpler also encouraging to avoid use 'deep'

Comment: This actually saved my day.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue and none of the solutions proposed actually solved the problem as I understood it. After working though some different ways of thinking about it, I believe that I figured out a manageable solution for dynamically changing the colors of mat-progress-bar when they are unknown before an API call (or user input).  I've created an [example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-mat-progressbar-colors) to play with, but it ultimately works like this:

1. On init, create a `style` `HTMLElement` that you can reference later.
2. On whatever trigger you desire (in the example, it's change of the input value) clear the style element, re-assign the colors to custom css, and re-attach to `head`

```
// in app.component.ts

  styleElement: HTMLStyleElement;
  colors : Array<string> = ["#ff00ff", "#00ff00"];

changeColors() {
  const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  const css = `
  .style1 .mat-progress-bar-fill::after {
    background-color: ${this.colors[0]} !important;
  }

  .style2 .mat-progress-bar-fill::after {
    background-color: ${this.colors[1]} !important;
  }
  `;
  this.styleElement.innerHTML = '';
  this.styleElement.type = 'text/css';
  this.styleElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  head.appendChild(this.styleElement);

}

ngOnInit() {
  this.styleElement = document.createElement('style');
  this.changeColors();
}
```

```
<!-- In app.component.html -->
<p>
  <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" value=70 class="style1"></mat-progress-bar>
</p><p>
  <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" value=40 class="style2"></mat-progress-bar>
</p>
<div><mat-form-field><input matInput type="color" placeholder="Style 1" [(ngModel)]="colors[0]" (change)="changeColors()" /></mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field><input matInput type="color" placeholder="Style 2" [(ngModel)]="colors[1]" (change)="changeColors()" /></mat-form-field></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[mat-progress-bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX2EC.png)

```
/deep/ .mat-progress-bar-fill::after {
    background-color: green;
}

/deep/ .mat-progress-bar-buffer {
    background: #E4E8EB;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular Material v15 components are now based on the official Material Design components for Web (MDC) which leads to some internal classes being changed.
This leads to the answer from [@HirenParekh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56917234/11325479) no longer working.
I updated the `changeColor()` method from his answer and extended it to also change the color of the buffer (the part of the progress bar not filled):

```js
  updateColor(): void{
    // update dynamic style with the uniqueAttr
    this.styleEl.innerText = `
      [${this.uniqueAttr}] .mdc-linear-progress__bar-inner {
        border-color: ${this.progressBarColor};
      }

      [${this.uniqueAttr}] .mdc-linear-progress__buffer-bar {
        background-color: ${this.progressBarColor}55 !important;
      }
    `;
  }
```