# how do I change the color of animated progress bar in my angular application

Tags: angular, angular-material, progress-bar

**ts**:

```
progress :any = 0;

ngOnInit() { setInterval(() => { this.progress += 1; }, 100)
```

**html:**

```
<mat-progress-bar style="height: 10px" mode="determinate" [value]="progress">
</mat-progress-bar>
```

this is an animated progress bar and I want to figure out how can I change the color of it after certain period like when the progress bar reaches 70% the color should change to yellow and when it reaches 90% the color should change to red

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52330515/change-angular-material-progress-bar-color-from-code) you are looking for?

Comment: no bro im looking for change in animated one they are just still progress bars

Comment: and i even want the change to happen in the same progress bar not in different bar